# I keep getting errors trying to install Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I get the following error trying to run NodeJs app on this domain https://ai.precisefinder.com/

this app has a video tutorial on how to run it . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGEeVuDWHzw&t=4s

I followed the steps but I get the following error :
503
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

can you anyone help me .

these are screenshots

[image: nodeJS]

[image: variables]

[image: server.js]

I followed the steps to install it in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGEeVuDWHzw&t=4s

I am supposed to get the app running

Comment: ...may I ask if you thought to check system error logs?

Comment: nope i did not . sorry im newbie . where to check in cpanel ?

Comment: cpanel is not your friend. Open your term and connect over SSH and _explore_ - otherwise you won't learn.

Comment: But FWIW, individual NodeJS applications don't log to disk by default, but I assume that 503 error is from the parent web-server (nginx?) - [cPanel's documentation](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4402325080727-Node-JS-Log-Location) links to this page for help diagnosing NodeJS issues: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/nodejs/#common-problems-specific-to-node.js

Comment: I found this error in stderr.log

/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48
    var app = require(startupFile);
              ^

Comment: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/hasanar/ai.precisefinder.com/server.js from /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js not supported.
Instead change the require of server.js in /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at startApplication (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:16:1) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48
    var app = require(startupFile);
              ^